# Incorrect alignment of side by side divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple left menu layout.

However, the div containing the main content is perfectly aligned side by side with the side menu.

The side menu is sitting directly below the navigation menu with no gap.

There is a small gap between the navigation menu and the main content of around 1cm. I have taken out all the padding and margins which hasn't made any difference.

Please could someone take a look at it as I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Left Menu Layout</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css" />
        <meta charset ="UTF-8">
    </head>

<body class="body">

    <header class="main-header">
        <img src="Images/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="main-content">

        <aside class="side-menu">
            <p>ABC</p>
        </aside>

        <div class="content">   
                <article class="top-content">   
                    <header>
                        <h2><a href="#" title="First Post">First Post</a></h2>
                    </header>                   
                    <footer>
                        <p class="post-info">This post if written by </p>
                    </footer>
                        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi </p>
                </article>

                <article class="bottom-content">    
                    <header>
                        <h2><a href="#" title="Second Post">First Post</a></h2>
                    </header>
                    <footer>
                        <p class="post-info">This post if written by </p>
                    </footer>                       
                        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                </article>
        </div>  

    </div>

    <footer class="main-footer">
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2013</p>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
/* ===========================
   ======= Body style ======== 
   =========================== */

body {
    background-image: url('Images/bg.png');
    color: #000305;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: left; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

.body {
    clear: both; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 960px;
}

/* ===========================
   ======= Anchor style ====== 
   =========================== */
a {
    outline: 0;
    }

a img {
    border: 0px; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    color: #CF5C3F;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #CF5C3F;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* ===========================
   ===== Main Navigation ===== 
   =========================== */

.main-header nav {
    background: #666;
    height: 40px;
}

.main-header nav ul li {
    float: left; 
    display: inline; 
}

.main-header nav a:link, .main-header nav a:visited {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* ===========================
   ======= Content Area ====== 
   =========================== */

.main-content {
    overflow: hidden;

}

.top-content {
    background-color: #FFF;

}

.bottom-content {
    background-color: #FFF; 

}

.content {
    width: 682px;
    float: left;

}

.post-info {
    font-style: italic;
    color: #999;
    font-size: 85%;
}

/* ===========================
   ======== Sidebar ========== 
   =========================== */

.side-menu {
    width: 268px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFF; 
}
```

Comment: mainly because of your h2 http://jsfiddle.net/LUp5f/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `<p>` always has its own margin. Reduce the margin around the `<p>` in your `<aside>` and it should solve the issue.

You can do this to the `<h2>` in your `<header>` as well if you need to pull that closer to your top navigation.

Comment: Thanks. This solved the problem. I have been looking at a CSS reset to remove all the preset formatting.

Comment: I avoid reset css files personally because then you get to know your HTML elements a little better, and you can understand their quirks, and use the defaults to make your CSS a little simpler to read. But that's totally a personal preference.